# Zurb Foundation: margin-top for class row doesn't work

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have two rows stacked and want the second to have a margin-top of 50px. But when I add a class "extramargin" for the second DIV and add margin-top:50px; it doesn't have any effect. When I put it in my HTML  it works.

Anybody here who knows how to add this extra spacing between those two rows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Try this may be:

```css
.row.extramargin {margin: 50px auto 10px !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks . Important did the job